# Are Subnets Truly Secure?

Tags: subnet

Subnets are managed at the VM level. A compromised VM can change it's subnet to loop through all the possibilities. By their very nature, surely they cannot be considered secure?

Note: I'm not a networking guru - so I may have missed something blindingly obvious...

Answer (score 3):

Subnets are a layer 3 division of network addresses. To prevent network traffic from reaching another subnet by changing the IP address to one in the other subnet you should consider 802.1q (VLAN tagging) which is a layer 2 separation of data.